# Filtering a map's key based on value in List<String>. Map is Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, java-8

I have a below code snippet

```
        String s = "Downloaded";
        Map<String, List<String>> m = Map.ofEntries(
                Map.entry("Download", List.of("Download", "Downloading,", "Downloaded")) ,
                Map.entry("Upload", List.of("Upload", "Uploading,", "Uploaded"))
        );
```

I want to stream over this map and if s partially matches with any of the items in List which is a value of one of the keys of the map, I want to return the key. How do I do with Streams? Also, the requirement is that as long as one of the strings is a superstring of `s`, I can still return the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a stream of the map entries, [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html). Filter by your criterion. Then extract the key from any matching entries. Collect those extracted keys.

```
 Collection < String > keys =
        map
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter( ( Map.Entry < String, List<String> > entry ) -> entry.getValue().contains( s ) )  // entry.getValue() returns a list of string objects. 
            .map( Map.Entry :: getKey )
            .collect( Collectors.toUnmodifiableList() ) ; // Or replace with `.toList()` in more modern Java.
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/5Ig7aZ).

> [Download]

I’m not sure of exactly what is your criterion of “superstring”. But tweaking that predicate seems like an incidental detail I can leave to you to work out.